# .htaccess problem

Tags: .htaccess

I'm new to apache's mod_rewrite and i'm having a problem ...

If i use the url : mysite.com/nl/ or mysite.com/fr/ i'm getting redirected to the right page, when a user enters the url mysite.com i redirect my user to the nl language but the problem is in the adress bar the url stays mysite.com and i would like it to be mysite.com/nl

this is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteBase /

# Rewrite voor taal en pagina
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ $1/$2 [R]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?tl=$1&pg=$2 [L]

#rewrite voor taal
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ $1 [R]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?tl=$1 [L]
```

my folder structure is:

```
[nl]
    index.php
    contact.php
[fr]
    index.php
    contact.php
index.php
```

the content of index.php (in the root directory):

```
<?
switch ($_REQUEST['tl'])
    {

        case 'nl':

            switch ($_REQUEST['pg'])
            {
                case 'contact':
                    include_once("nl/contact.php");
                break;

                default:
                    include_once("nl/index.php");
                break;
            }


        break;

        case 'fr':
                include_once("fr/index.php");
        break;

        default:
            include_once("nl/index.php");
        break;
    }
?>
```

So when a users enters mysite.com it shows the index.php from the nl directory but the url in the browser address stays mysite.com but should be mysite.com/nl/

Since i have zero experience in this rewriting rules i've been stuck at it for hours ...

Thanks in advance,

Davidi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `include_once` try using `header('Location: /nl/page.php')` or `header('Location: /fr/page.php');`